# SVG Mask not working with illustrator generated SVGs (all browsers)

Tags: html, css, svg, masking

So right to it -

I have two SVGs, the first is a blue circle and the second is a map of the US. (both created in Illustrator)

I want the map the be the mask of the blue ball.

The end goal is to animate the blue ball to fill in the map.

But first I need to make these masks work, which I cannot, I've tried a clipping path as well however that solution only worked in FF and not with any file created in Illustrator.

This is as close as I have gotten to getting a mask to work, this only works in Chrome.

I am using
    `.class {clip-path: url(#clipping);}` method.

http://codepen.io/CiderZombie/pen/EPzyeN

In that example the circle is the mask, when I switch the map and the circle it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Clipping and masking of HTML elements is still has inconsistent and partial support in browsers.

[Dirk Schultz's article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) covers it pretty well.

If you want reliable clipping and masking, you may be stuck with masking SVG elements only.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="usmap">
      <path d="m8 18 62 6 9 10 l 19 -12 1 6 -4 22 -10 17 7 15 -2 1 -13 -14 -18 -1 -12 13 -13 -16 -19 -1 -14 -21 1 -16z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#DF090C" clip-path="url(#usmap)"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="blue" clip-path="url(#usmap)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm surprised how inconsistent this is. Thanks!